# Multiple series data Highcharts line

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

The result of query I use display 3 column (country, date, items).
My php code side

```
 $res = db_query($sql);
$dat = array(); 
while($r = db_fetch_array($res)){
    $dat[]= array($r['date'], $r['items'], $r['country']);
}

// Armar
$start_date = '';
if(count($dat)>0){
    $s = split(' ',$dat[0][0]);
    $ss = split('-',$s[0]);
}
// Cada objeto en $dats es una grafica
$dats[] = array('type'=>'line',
            'name'=>$q['title'],
            'pointInterval'=>24 * 3600 * 1000,
            'pointStart'=>mktime(0,0,0,$ss[1],$ss[2],$ss[0])*1000,
            'data'=>$dat) ;
//echo "$sql";
echo json_encode($dats,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

My Javascript Code :

```
function loadLine(_data){
    $('#line_container').highcharts({
        chart: {zoomType: 'x',spacingRight: 20},
        title: { text: 'Monthly Created items'},
        subtitle: {text:'Updated every day'},
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            maxZoom: 7 * 24 * 3600000, // fourteen days
            title: {text: null}
        },
        yAxis: {title: {text: 'Created items'}},
        tooltip: {shared: true},
        legend: {enabled: true},
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                shadow: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },
        series: _data
    });
}
```

and The result displayed is like this
[image]

How Could change "series 1" in the graph by the country name I receive in my query?
The data I have in the Query has date until "April" (YTD) but the Graph shows Months in the future, How could I correct this?
If I have more than 1 country in my Query How could I display this in multiple chart lines at the same time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If no answer below solved your problem so far, then please provide content of `_data` - what is returned by your query into JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only supplied a single series, which will only translate to a single line. Try something like:

```
 $res = db_query($sql);
$dat = array(); 
while($r = db_fetch_array($res)){
    if (!isset($dat[$r['country']])) 
       $dat[$r['country']] = [];

    $dat[$r['country']][] = array($r['date'], $r['items'], $r['country']);
}

// Armar
$start_date = '';
if(count($dat)>0){
    $s = split(' ',$dat[0][0]);
    $ss = split('-',$s[0]);
}
// Cada objeto en $dats es una grafica
$dats = [];
foreach ($dat as $country => $values) {
$dats[] = array('type'=>'line',
            'name'=>$q['title'],
            'pointInterval'=>24 * 3600 * 1000,
            'pointStart'=>mktime(0,0,0,$ss[1],$ss[2],$ss[0])*1000,
            'data'=>$values) ;
}
//echo "$sql";
echo json_encode($dats,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `_data` should be something like the following:

```
 [{
        name: 'USA',
        data: [[Date.UTC(2013,5,1), 7.0], [Date.UTC(2013,6,1), 5.0]]
    }, {
        name: 'Germany',
        data: [[Date.UTC(2013,5,1), 6.0], [Date.UTC(2013,6,1), 8.0]]
    }, {
        name: 'Japan',
        data: [[Date.UTC(2013,5,1), 7.0], [Date.UTC(2013,6,1), 3.0]]
  }]
```

So you will need to do some mapping from your `_data`